# Generating random sequences of DNA

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I am trying to generate random sequences of DNA in python using random numbers and random strings. But I am getting only one string as my output. For example: If I give DNA of length 5 (String(5)), I should get an output "CTGAT". Similarly if I give String(4) it should give me "CTGT". But I am getting "G" or "C" or "T" or "A"; i.e. only a single string each time. Could anyone please help me with this??

I tried the following code:

```
from random import choice
def String(length):

   DNA=""
   for count in range(length):
      DNA+=choice("CGTA")
      return DNA
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You return too quickly:

```
from random import choice
def String(length):

   DNA=""
   for count in range(length):
      DNA+=choice("CGTA")
      return DNA
```

If your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, you will only iterate once --- you will exit out of the function with the `return`.

From the [Python Documentation on `return` statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement):
"**return leaves the current function call** with the expression list (or None) as return value."

So, put the `return` at the end of your function:

```
def String(length):

       DNA=""
       for count in range(length):
          DNA+=choice("CGTA")
       return DNA
```

EDIT: Here's a weighted choice method (it will only work for strings currently, since it uses string repetition).

```
def weightedchoice(items): # this doesn't require the numbers to add up to 100
    return choice("".join(x * y for x, y in items))
```

Then, you want to call `weightedchoice` instead of `choice` in your loop:

`DNA+=weightedchoice([("C", 10], ("G", 20), ("A", 40"), ("T", 30)])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. Can i add a distribution which is a list of tuples for example String(10,[("a",20),("b",60),("c",20)]) where the probabilities sum to 100(20+60+20)

Answer (score 10):

I'd generate the string all in one go, rather than build it up. Unless Python's being clever and optimising the string additions, it'll reduce the runtime complexity from quadratic to linear.

```
import random

def DNA(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice('CGTA') for _ in xrange(length))

print DNA(5)
```

Comment: Whoever voted down should have left a note (such as "the question is about understanding code blocks and indentation"). Using `str.join()` is _much_ faster than adding letters (DNA bases) one by one.

Comment: instead of random.choice('CGTA') you can put the frequency for each base down, like this: random.choice("A"*5+"C"*4+"G"*3+"T"*10). Replace the numbers I gave by the real relative numbers you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps numpy works faster thanks to vectorization?:

```
import numpy as np
seq_length = 100
my_seq = ''.join(np.random.choice(('C','G','T','A'), seq_length ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded the code to provide GC percent distribution from 0 to 100%. The code above always produces a 50% distribution.

The actg_distribution string can be any length of an existing DNA sequence of known GC percent. GC percent of a certain range is a common use case.

```
import random

# Return random CGTA sequences, set minimum = maximum to get a specified length.
def random_length_dnasequence(minimum=25, maximum=10000, actg_distribution=None):
    if (minimum == maximum):
        length = minimum
    else:
        length = random.randint(minimum, maximum)
    if (actg_distribution == None):
        actg_distribution = ''.join(random.choice('cgta') for _x in xrange(7))

    return ''.join(random.choice(actg_distribution) for _x in xrange(length))


def random_dnasequence(length, actg_distribution=None):
    return random_length_dnasequence(length, length, actg_distribution)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast function for python 3.6 using random.choices

```
import random

def string(length=int(), letters="CGTA"):
        #slower 0.05s for 20000 nt
#     dna =""
#     for count in range(length):
#         dna+=choice("CGTA")
#     return dna

    #0.013s for 20000 nt
    return''.join(random.choices(letters, k=length)
```